# Supabase - RLS on a logical view?

Tags: postgresql, supabase-database

I’m trying to work out whether Supabase supports row level security on logical views.
In my case, the logical view is a query on a table that does have RLS.
I saw a response somewhere else that suggests that RLS is supported on logical views if the view ownership is changed to ‘authenticated’. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

That was true until [Postgres 15](https://supabase.com/blog/new-in-postgres-15) came along. With postgres 15, you can create a security invoker view, which respects RLS with no additional configuration.

You can create a security invoker view like this:

```sql
create or replace view my_view
    with (security_invoker = on) as
        select *
        from public.my_table;
```